# How to design grid Rowdefinitions and Columndefinitions dynamically for Windows7 phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

i need to design grid Rowdefinitions and Columndefinitions  dynamically for Windows7 phone
please help me

Thanking you

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean at runtime then you can easily access the grid and add what you need programatically at any time.

Simply add a Name to the grid and go to work on its RowDefinitions and ColumnDefinitions properties.

```
<Grid x:Name="myGrid"/>

myGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = GridLength.Auto });
```